# Do these outputs seem normal for the order finding algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, cirq

I'm sorry for posting so many questions about this specific problem, but I just want to make sure that I am implementing an algorithm correctly. I am simulating the order finding algorithm (finding minimal $r$ for $x^r \ = \ 1$mod($N)$). Right now, I am trying to implement the case of $x \ = \ 2$ and $N \ = \ 5$. I am getting outputs that look somewhat like this:

[image]

When I pass these results through the continued fraction algorithm, I'm getting the expected results of the algorithm, however, these results seem weird, as they are basically just every combination of $1$ and $0$ for the first two qubits. I just want to make sure that I am actually implementing the algorithm correctly, and not just getting lucky with my results. Again, I'm very sorry for all the questions about this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

This looks right, although I would emphasise that it is not really best practice to have to ask this question at this stage. The whole point of doing a particularly simple example is so that you can confirm that it's doing what you've *already calculated analytically*. It's quite important to do the analytic bit first to avoid confirmation bias.

Anyway, let's see what we should get. I'm going to assume a first register (the one that we do the Fourier transform etc on) contains $t$ qubits. I'm guessing that $t=7$ from your output. We start with the system in $|0\rangle^{\otimes t}|1\rangle$, and apply the Hadamard transform to the first register:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^t}}\sum_{j=0}^{2^t-1}|j\rangle|1\rangle.
$$
Then we apply the modular exponentiation
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^t}}\sum_{j=0}^{2^t-1}|j\rangle|2^j\text{ mod }5\rangle.
$$
We can simply this as
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^t}}\sum_{k=0}^3\left(\sum_{j=0}^{2^{t-2}-1}|k+4j\rangle\right)|2^k\text{ mod }5\rangle.
$$

Now, instead of simply applying the inverse Quantum Fourier Transform, I prefer to think about its action on states. The QFT (not inverse), transforms basis states
$$
|x\rangle\rightarrow|\psi_x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^t}}\sum_{y=0}^{2^t-1}\omega^{xy}|y\rangle
$$
where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/2^t}$, so we want to describe our states such as $|0\rangle+|4\rangle+|8\rangle+|12\rangle+\ldots$ in terms of $|\psi_x\rangle$ to know what values of $x$ we might get as output from the inverse QFT. But we can easily observe that
$$
|0\rangle+|4\rangle+|8\rangle+|12\rangle+\ldots=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{x=0}^3|\psi_{2^{t-2}x}\rangle.
$$
Hence, for the $k=0$ case, we get each of the 4 answers $0,2^{t-2},2^{t-1},3\times 2^{t-2}$ with equal probability. These are the 4 bit strings that you're seeing on output. Similarly, the other 3 values of $k$ can be decomposed also in terms of $\{|\psi_{2^{t-2}x}\rangle\}_{x=0}^3$, just with different multiplicative factors (fourth roots of unity), the point being that these 4 vectors all have period 4 and they form a basis for the states $|0\rangle$ to $|3\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one question, you say that I am getting these solutions for 4 bit strings in my output, what exactly do you mean by that (since I have a 7 bit register)?

Comment: I mean that there are 4 answers, each of which is a bit string. In this case, you're talking about the 7 bit representations of the numbers 0 (0000000), $2^{t-2}$ (0100000), $2^{t-1}$ (1000000) and $3\times 2^{t-2}$ (1100000).